# Cube corner creates at fixed point for some reason

Tags: mesh

Perhaps I tweaked something, but currently (no matter which mode is) when I try to add cube, start corner is always fixed at constant point.

Normally, the start corner is where I clicked, but now clicking actually defines the opposite diagonal corner, but the start corner is fixed.

I did not try to restart Blender, I will do it, but just want to know, maybe I turned on something.

[image]

---

The problem is still occures after Blender restart, but only in my current project. In other projects, there is no such behaviour, so probably I tweaked something.

---

It seems that after switching on Gizoms button (it was switched off) the problem is solved, but if I switch it back to off, all is still fine. Perhaps bug?

Comment: Do you have snapping turned on?  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html

Comment: @KickAir8p, thought about that, but no, I remember that I checked it and it was disabled